# How to find value from Object using another value with jsonpath?

Tags: json, rest-assured, jsonpath, rest-assured-jsonpath

Example JSON file:

```
{
  "propertyName1": {
    "name": "Anthony",
    "age": 10
  },
  "propertyName2": {
    "name": "Eric",
    "age": 12
  }
}
```

I need to find the name which age is 10 for example

```
("properyName1.find{it.age == '10'}.name"). is not working, the propertyName1 is not an array
```

I need this because in this example I know the age, and with age, I want to find the name.
How can I find the needed data?

Comment: have you tried `*[?(@.age == 10)].name`

Comment: Hey Gabriele, no it not works

Comment: you only need `find` when you search in an array. `properyName1` is an object, so it doesn't work

Comment: lucasnguyen17 yeah I know it, and how can I solve my problem without using find?

Answer (score 1):

JsonPath has quite different syntax, so I believe this one should be working for you:

`String ageValue = response.path("propertyName1.age").toString();`

`// path() method returns Object by default, but as you see, you can cast to the type what you need.`